# How to select lines between { and } inclusive in powershell using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to remove text from a file between { and } inclusive but only if it contains the string "RG " - the third and fourth group in the following. (Note that if it is the last in the list it will not have the trailing comma.)

```
     "morphs" : [
        {
           "uid" : "AQ_Eun-Ju-Body-2022-31-7--15_02_30.592.vmi",
           "name" : "AQ_Eun-Ju-Body",
           "value" : "1"
        },
        {
           "uid" : "AQ_Eun-Ju-Head-2022-31-7--15_02_30.592.vmi",
           "name" : "AQ_Eun-Ju-Head",
           "value" : "1"
        },
        {
           "uid" : "RG side2side.vmi",
           "name" : "RG side2side",
           "value" : "-0.3332869"
        },
        {
           "uid" : "RG UpDown2.vmi",
           "name" : "RG UpDown2",
           "value" : "-0.3332869"
        }
     ]
```

I can get it to work with `-replace '.*{\n.\*RG .\*\n.\*\n.\*\n.\*}.\*\n',''` however if the group does not have three lines it fails because of the explicit linefeeds. I can create a replace for each number of lines but that seems clunky.  I tried `'RG.\*?},\*\n'` which gives me the last part, but I'm struggling with the first part.

This is what I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem $VAMfixDir -recurse -include *.json,*.vap,*.vaj | Where-Object { $timestamp -lt $_.CreationTime } |
Foreach-Object {  
    $originalContent = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
    # *Potentially* perform replacements, depending on whether the search patterns are found.
    $potentiallyModifiedContent = $originalContent -Replace ".*{\n.*RG .*\n.*\n.*\n.*}.*\n|.*{\n.*RG .*\n.*\n.*}.*\n",""
    Set-Content -NoNewLine -Encoding Ascii -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Value $potentiallyModifiedContent
    }
```

EDIT: The file in the example above that I'm trying to edit IS a json file, but I'm trying to create a POWERSHELL script to remove groups of lines from it using REGEX. I have shown the regex that works but it has its limitations, as stated. I was hoping for a more elegant solution than a massive OR'd -Replace statement.

Comment: Why did you change the tag? it is the RegEX that i'm asking for help with not the Json file.

Comment: This looks like JSON.  One alternative to look into is using [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.3)/[ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.3).  Read/convert to objects, filter out (e.g. `Where-Object`) the 'RG' ones, then re-export as JSON.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to use `ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As noted, it's generally preferable to use a dedicated parser and serializer for parsing JSON data, namely [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) and [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)
- However, [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based transformations may be an option if you're looking to preserve the exact formatting of the input file and/or the desired transformations are syntactically limited in a way that allows them to based on regexes *reliably*, which does appear to be the case here.

```bash
$potentiallyModifiedContent = 
  $originalContent -Replace '(?:,\s*)?\{[^}]+\bRG\b[^}]+\}'
```

For a detailed explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/U5Alos/2).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `.*{\n.\*RG .\*\n.\*\n.\*\n.\*}.\*\n`

- While not *always* necessary (it isn't in this case), it's best to *routinely* escape `{` and `}` characters meant to be taken *literally*, given that these characters are *metacharacters* used for *quantifiers*, with the proper syntax between them (e.g., `{2}` matches the previous subexpression exactly `2` times)
- Conversely, if you do want `*` to be treated as a metacharacter (a quantifier matching the preceding subexpression zero or more times), do *not* escape it (as `\*`).
- In general, you can use the `SingleLine` regex option to make `.` match newlines too, so that `.*` would match across lines. The simplest way to activate this option is to place `(?s)` at the start of the regex.
- `{\n.\*RG` - if corrected to `\{\n.*RG` or even to the *non-greedy* `\{\n.*?RG` - is too permissive, as it will start matching at the first `{`, even if that block does *not* contain `RG` and keep matching across the end of that and potentially later ones until `RG` *is* found in a block.
- Ultimately, it's best to use `[^{]+` and `[^}]+`, as shown above, to match the characters after the opening `{` and before the closing `}`, which implicitly matches across lines too.

See also:

- Since PowerShell's regex functionality builds on .NET's, see the [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).